# How to connect a Control and its Label by VBA-Code?

Tags: ms-access, vba

In MS Access, when I create a new control by the visual designer, there is also a label. The label is connected to the control.

Now, I create my control and label by VBA-Code.

How can I connect them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `CreateControl` function to create your label you should pass your `TextBox`'s control name in `Parent` parameter, as described in function declaration:
`Function CreateControl(FormName As String, ControlType As AcControlType, [Section As AcSection = acDetail], [Parent], [ColumnName], [Left], [Top], [Width], [Height]) As Control`

For example function that populates existed form with 250 pair of linked TextBoxes and labels:

```
Public Sub PopulateFormWithControls(fNAme As String)
'PopulateFormWithControls "msrForm4Table"
    Dim f As Form
    Dim ctrlFld As Control
    Dim ctrlCap As Control
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim col As Byte
    Dim Y As Long
    DoCmd.OpenForm fNAme, acDesign
    Set f = Forms(fNAme)
    For i = 1 To 250
        Set ctrlFld = CreateControl(f.name, acTextBox, , , , 4000 + 8000 * col, Y, 4000, 300)
        ctrlFld.name = "fld" & Format(i)

        Set ctrlCap = CreateControl(f.name, acLabel, , ctrlFld.name, , 0 + 8000 * col, Y, 4000, 300)
        ctrlCap.name = "cap" & Format(i)

        Y = Y + 300

        If i Mod 100 = 0 Then
            col = col + 1
            Y = 0
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I was short before this solution. My fault was to use "ctrl" as parameter, but "ctrl.name" is needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the control's property *LabelName* to hold the name of the label.

[What's new in Access 2019](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/What-s-new-in-Access-2019-f52c5317-3494-4105-9c56-5a2abb8e0f87)

In older versions: mark the label, cut it, mark the control, paste the label into the control.

Comment: cut&paste isn't doable with VBA, or is there any Clipboard command that I can call? .... so far, I am testing around with the "Parent" property. But no success so far. Its readonly.

Comment: Not that I know of, sorry.But why not create those controls that may be needed, and hide those not needed until so.

Comment: I create the form by vba-code. To have a connection between a label and the right control, it would be fine, if the parent would be set.